# How To Select Data From Two Tables In Django?

Tags: python, django

Using `django` I have created two classes, but I have a problem in relation between tables and selecting rows:

```
class ayoub (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sname=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class sabri(models.Model):
    a=models.ForeignKey(ayoub, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sname=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to display all the attributes of `sabri` with the attribute name from class `ayoub` not the `primary key (id)`

Comment: what you need and what have you tried?? output needed?? can you post?

Answer (score 1):

```
sabri.objects.filter(a__name='something').values('name','sname')
```

if you need name and sname from ayoub class you can try this query

```
sabri.objects.filter(a__name='something').values('name','sname','a__name','a__sname')
```

Comment: thank u i will try this method and i will let u a comment if i got any problem

Comment: i didn't understand what  i will replace 'something' @Exprator

Comment: With the name that you want to search with

Comment: i do like that and work success i don't know it's correct or not `sabri.a.name`

Comment: i don't want search name . i don't wanti display `sabri.pk` i want name on refrences key in ayoub